# How to iteratively use INSERT INTO in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have Table1 with rows I want to iterate over, and insert values from those rows of data into another table.

```
Table1Name     ->      ID      Name  Date        Type
--------               -------------------------------
a                      101     a     2021-07-01  original
b                      139     b     2021-07-04  original
c                      322     c     2021-07-08  original
d                      431     d     2021-07-09  original
```

So basically pseudo is:

```
Loop over Table1:
    INSERT INTO Table2 (id, name, date) VALUES (random(), Table1.name, NOW(), 'original')
```

Just looping through Table1, adding in one of its values every time.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff added some extra details

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just want an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` here:

```
INSERT INTO Table2 (id, name, date)
SELECT RANDOM(), name, NOW()
FROM Table1;
```

Most SQL operations are inherently *set* based, meaning if you want to insert all records from one table into another, the operation would be viewed as a single thing.

Comment: hey I added some more details, there are other values I'd want to pass in too.

Comment: @chung I have updated my answer, but I'm sticking with my general premise.

Comment: oh I didn't know you could add like "RANDOM()" into a select, thanks!

Comment: Could/Should you use something like [`nextval()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-sequence.html) for an `id` column which is likely to be a serial datatype?